# Apple Wallpaper gone in recent versions of iOS?

Tags: ios, wallpaper

Has Apple been replacing their Wallpaper images during updates of iOS 7, 8, and 9?

My iPhone 5s has an image of a blue-green aurora borealis that I assume was Apple-provided. I don't recall installing from outside. But now I do not see that image listed in Settings > Wallpaper > Choose a New Wallpaper > Apple Wallpaper in iOS 9.2.

Comment: Try [searching for iOS wallpapers @ Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=ios+wallpapers+download&client=safari&rls=en&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAvciL6dzJAhXDmR4KHV97BI0QsAQIHA&biw=1363&bih=1159)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Nearly every iOS update phases out some of the wallpapers and introduces new ones. They typically phase out the oldest wallpapers while adding new ones into the mix. Many of the earlier iOS versions introduced and phased out fewer images, but the last few have introduced more, and subsequently removed more.

The dynamic wallpapers have stayed the same since they were introduced in iOS 7.

Comment: And though images are removed from the *options*, once your wallpaper is set it will stay until you change it.

Comment: @timothymh But how to save and later reset that particular image that I like and that Apple deleted?

Comment: If you just search for it on Google Images or the like, I'm sure you can find any deleted images.

Comment: @BasilBourque If you find the image that you like, you can easily set it by saving it to your camera roll, tapping the share icon, and then selecting it as your wallpaper.