# All the wallpapers included in iPhone 13 are gone in iOS 16.2

Tags: iphone, ios, wallpaper

I'm using iPhone 13 with iOS 16.2. As recently as a few weeks ago, I was able to go to Settings -> Wallpaper and be presented with a nice gallery of different wallpapers that I could set to my home and lockscreen, including solid colors, abstract art, nature and space scenes, etc.

However, today I just noticed that the Settings -> Wallpaper screen looks totally different: one "panel" just says "current", with my current wallpaper (which is an abstract art one mentioned above), along with an "add new" button. When I tap "add new", I'm presented with what appears to be some sort of "App store", except it's more of a "wallpaper store", and all the different wallpapers mentioned above are nowhere to be found. The new selection includes things like a "globe view" that has my location on it, some emoji wallpapers, and some other stuff.

Is this an actual consequence of one of the recent updates? Are all of those original wallpapers that I used to be able to pick gone forever?

Note there is [a similarly named question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219642/apple-wallpaper-gone-in-recent-versions-of-ios), but that question pertains to an ancient version of iOS so surely is unrelated to what I'm seeing here.

Comment: The highest voted answer in the linked question is still applicable. Why do you believe it no longer applied?